# How to join the same table and calculate data in SQL alchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a table looks like this:

```
| id | company_name | income | year |
|----|--------------|--------|------|
| 0  | A            | 10     | 2010 |
| 1  | A            | 20     | 2011 |
| 2  | A            | 30     | 2012 |
| 3  | B            | 20     | 2010 |
| 4  | B            | 15     | 2011 |
```

I want to get a table of A like this:

```
|                | 2010 | 2011 | 2012 |
|----------------|------|------|------|
| income         | 10   | 20   | 30   |
| increase_ratio | -    | 2    | 1.5  |
```

In SQL I can get this kind of result by using alias and join, but how can I get this using `python SQL alchemy` ?

The database of the table is `MySQL`, schema of the original table looks like :

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Integer, Float, String
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column

metadata = MetaData()

income = Table(
    'income', metadata,
    Column('company_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('company_name', String(255), nullable=False),
    Column('income', Float, nullable=False),
    Column('year', Integer, nullable=False),
)
```

Comment: You'd use an alias and a join as well: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-aliases, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-joins

Comment: Which server you are using, SQL server, MySQL or anything else?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 'Income' AS ` `, MAX(CASE WHEN Year= 2010 THEN income END)`2010`
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Year= 2011 THEN income END)`2011`
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Year= 2012 THEN income END)`2012`
from(
  SELECT A.*,(A.income/B.income)increase_ratio
  FROM My_Table A
  LEFT JOIN My_Table B ON B.id = A.id-1
  WHERE A.company_name = 'A'
  )D
 UNION
 select 'increase_ratio' AS ` `,MAX(CASE WHEN Year= 2010 THEN increase_ratio END)`2010`
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Year= 2011 THEN increase_ratio END)`2011`
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN Year= 2012 THEN increase_ratio END)`2012`
from(
  SELECT A.*,(A.income/B.income)increase_ratio
  FROM My_Table A
  LEFT JOIN My_Table B ON B.id = A.id-1
  WHERE A.company_name = 'A'
  )D
```

Check this in the [#SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/534229/10)

**Output:**

```
                2010    2011    2012
Income          10      20      30
increase_ratio  (null)  2      1.5
```

Comment: thanks for this nice script, I'll try to convert this into sql alchemy form to see if it works.